# How do I find all repeating character sequences in a string?

Tags: c#, string, foreach, sequence, identifier

Hello Im finding it difficult to make this adaptation in my code. Currently it can identify repeated words but what about repeated characters sequences?

For example if the user inputs:  the rest is a test

the program will output:  MOST COMMON: "est"  (but I cant get this to work)

Or if the user inputs: same game

the program will output: MOST COMMON: "ame"

It must be Case sensitive ("XY can not be treated as the same as xY or Xy"). Here is my current code:

```
  string words;
    Console.WriteLine("Input string:");
    words = Console.ReadLine();
    var results = words.Split(' ').Where(x => x.Length > 3)
                                  .GroupBy(x => x)
                                  .Select(x => new { Count = x.Count(), Word = x.Key })
                                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);

    foreach (var item in results)


    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} occured {1} times", item.Word, item.Count));
    Console.WriteLine("Most common = " + results.First());
    Console.WriteLine("Least common =  "+ results.Last());
```

Comment: The code you have above only splits on space and groups by those. Can you show your attempt to identify strings of letters? What's wrong with it? This sounds like a homework assignment...

Comment: What do you mean by character sequence? Any constraints on the length? Why the input "the rest is a test" does not return "t" as most common?

Comment: How many characters your substring should be ?

Answer (score 2):

Split into words, assume minimum length is 3 characters, find most frequent then longest common sequence:

```
var results = words.Split(' ')
                   .SelectMany(w => Enumerable.Range(3, Math.Max(0, w.Length - 2)).Select(n => w.Substring(w.Length - n, n)))
                   .GroupBy(pw => pw)
                   .Select(pwg => new { Common = pwg.Key, Count = pwg.Count() })
                   .OrderByDescending(cc => cc.Count)
                   .ThenByDescending(cc => cc.Common.Length)
                   .Take(1);
```